# Changing background color of RectangleShape in Visual Basic Power Pack 3 with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, powerpack

I've installed Visual Basic Power Pack 3 in Visual Studio 2008 SP1. 
I wanna change the background color of RectangleShape in a C# WinForm !!! 
I changed `FillColor` property and `BackColor` property to `Black` but nothing happened and  RectangleShape's  background color didn't changed.

How can I change the background color of  RectangleShape ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you set the FillStyle to Solid?

Answer (score 2):

Change the BackStyle property from "Transparent" to "Opaque".  Click around some more to see what effects the properties have, the designer support is pretty good.